# Spacing for readablity purposes

Tags: php

I want to print some tabs of white space in order to easily read the information printed. However I tried to use several approaches and none seem to work. I tried:

```
str_repeat('&#x00009;', 5)
str_repeat('&#9;', 5).
"\x20" 
"\t" 
"   "
```

On every case I got the same result, no space. Is it because I'm only using PHP?

Comment: Have you tried `&nbsp;` or `<pre></pre>`, `var_dump`, `print_r`?

Comment: Not yet, but will try now. Thanks

Comment: the $nbsp; works. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It's more like an HTML issue. Basically all consecutive white spaces are compressed into single spaces, unless you include the text in a `<pre>` tag, and even then the tabs will not work as in your average text editor.

If you want to tabulate something, you'll have to create an HTML format (using CSS margins or a table or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Html will hide (or just not display) all tabs and multiple whitespaces.

by using `<pre></pre>` tags, you could display tabs:

```
echo '<pre>'.str_repeat('&#9;', 5).'</pre>';
```

For readability though, you should use a html table (if you want to display tabbed data). This way you don't need tabs anymore.

Probably the only reason using pre and tabs is advised is when you want to display formatted/styled code on your website. For this there are a lot of libraries that can style your code (so you won't need to do this).